# Docker container hangs with no apparent fault

Tags: docker

**Update: Problem is reported on version 1.9.1 and is not present in up-to-date versions of Docker.**

I have an docker app running in elasticbeanstalk that hangs after about 10-11 days of uptime.

The app runs a cron job every minute. There is no long-running application process (of mine).

Once it has hung, it no longer responds to HTTP requests.

The following `docker` commands hang: `top`, `exec`, `restart`

`docker logs` responds but shows no error.

I do not know how to debug further from this point. Any ideas?

`docker inspect` shows:

```
{
    "Id": "a9e7ed019ce543073c16507036d1a5579817a0e0abf79e6f79949bcc96dca444",
    "Created": "2016-06-16T22:29:57.448398251Z",
    "Path": "/usr/local/bin/init.sh",
    "Args": [],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 4406,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2016-06-16T22:29:58.459393626Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "6aa1c5468fbe4102e7428d4325f666868498b9880c9dc3f14c30c2a6804a25a5",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a9e7ed019ce543073c16507036d1a5579817a0e0abf79e6f79949bcc96dca444/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a9e7ed019ce543073c16507036d1a5579817a0e0abf79e6f79949bcc96dca444/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a9e7ed019ce543073c16507036d1a5579817a0e0abf79e6f79949bcc96dca444/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a9e7ed019ce543073c16507036d1a5579817a0e0abf79e6f79949bcc96dca444/a9e7ed019ce543073c16507036d1a5579817a0e0abf79e6f79949bcc96dca444-json.log",
    "Name": "/cranky_hugle",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "devicemapper",
    "ExecDriver": "native-0.2",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": [
        "8de1c20fc2c90e7a41c709e226ecd3401db18c6e0044527b4cc205d15167ac6d"
    ],
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LxcConf": [],
        "Memory": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "MemorySwappiness": -1,
        "Privileged": false,
        "PortBindings": {},
        "Links": null,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "Dns": [],
        "DnsOptions": [],
        "DnsSearch": [],
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "Devices": [],
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "IpcMode": "",
        "PidMode": "",
        "UTSMode": "",
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "VolumeDriver": ""
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Name": "devicemapper",
        "Data": {
            "DeviceId": "46",
            "DeviceName": "docker-202:1-263679-a9e7ed019ce543073c16507036d1a5579817a0e0abf79e6f79949bcc96dca444",
            "DeviceSize": "107374182400"
        }
    },
    "Mounts": [],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "a9e7ed019ce5",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "443/tcp": {},
            "80/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "ENV=prd",
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data",
            "APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data",
            "APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2",
            "GIT_REV=76bf2a3207482a0dfc06551374056480946825ff"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "/usr/local/bin/init.sh"
        ],
        "Image": "6aa1c5468fbe",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {},
        "StopSignal": "SIGTERM"
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "*********",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "443/tcp": null,
            "80/tcp": null
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/*********",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "*********",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "*********",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "EndpointID": "*********",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "*********"
            }
        }
    }
}
]
```

Comment: What Docker version?  There are a veritable cornucopia of bugs in various versions of Docker which could conceivably be causing the symptoms you describe.

Comment: Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5/1.9.1

Comment: Any update on this since Jun 28 '16?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of Docker you're running is *chock* full of bugs that can cause problems managing containers.  We were whacking containers left and right until Docker 1.11 came out, the new architecture of which makes is much more stable and reliable in this sense.  I strongly recommend upgrading.

Comment: Someone came through and downvoted us both, cest la vie. I appreciate your answer womble. It is useful. I've upgraded and I'll see if the problem recurs.

Comment: The problem no longer occurred after upgrading.

Comment: Story of my life when it comes to Docker.